# Form POST submission doesn't generate $_POST key-values as expected

Tags: php

Hello all and thanks in advance for the help,

I am struggling to understand why the PHP code I have is not looping through each input field and posting/getting the output.

```
<html>

<body>
    <!-- This PHP code will loop through all of the input fields and output the IDs and names. Both options of the get and post methods are checked. -->
    <?php

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br/>";
    }
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br/>";
    }

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the form I am trying to get to work

```
   <form class="form" action="response_page.php" method="post">
            <div class="form__group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to put `name` attribute in your form input items, like this:

```html
         <form class="form" action="response_page.php" method="post">
            <div class="form__group">
                <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form__input" required>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
        </form>
```

Without the `name` attribute, the browser won't know what key to use for each fields.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

The names of html input elements in a form are used as “key” in http get / post array on form submit.

Your input elements do not have any name property. So they are not submitted properly. Add names to inputs. For example

```
<input type="password" name=“password” placeholder="Password" class="form__input" required>
```